# Deducing $L^1$ convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_i$ be iid, non-negative with mean $1$ and $M_0=1$, $M_n=X_1 X_2\cdots X_n$ an martingale with respect to the natural filtration. If I know that $E[\mathbb{1}_{\{max_{1\leq k \leq n}M_k \geq c\}}]\leq \frac{1}{c}$, that $E[M_k]=1$ for all $k$, and that $M_n$ converges to some finite $M_{\infty}$ almost surely, can I conclude that $(M_n)$ converges to it in $L^1$?

Comment: Are $c$ and $\lambda$ related?

Comment: Edited, sorry about that

Comment: I believe you need a stronger inequality for $L^{1}$ convergence but I don't have a counter-example at the moment.

Comment: For the Scheffe Lemma, I would need $E[M_n]$ converging to $E[M_{\infty}]$ in order to conclude L1 convergence, and I don't think I have that, I don't know the L1 norm of  $E[M_{\infty}]$.

Comment: What if instead I know $E[M_n \mathbb{1}_{\{max_{1\leq k \leq n}M_k \geq c}]\leq 1$ for all $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot conclude this without a stronger condition on $M$.  Doob's inequality will always give that $\mathbb{P}(\max_{1 \le k \le n} M_k \ge c) \le \frac 1c \mathbb{E}[M_n 1_{\max_{1 \le k \le n} M_k \ge c}] \le \frac 1c \mathbb{E}[M_n] = \frac 1c$ whenever $M$ is a martingale of this form.

For a specific counterexample, let $X_i$ be i.i.d. with $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 2) = \mathbb{P}(X_i = 0) = \frac 12$.  Then $M_n = X_1 X_2 \cdots X_n$ converges to $M_{\infty} = 0$ almost surely because $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 2 \text{ for all }i \in \mathbb{N}) = 0$, and since $\mathbb{E}[M_n] = 1$ for all $n$ we can't have $(M_n) \rightarrow M_{\infty}$ in $L^1$

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the previous answer, it is false.

I am posting this just to add a counterexample where $X_n>0$.

Let $(W_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a Brownian Motion and let $X_n = e^{W_n-W_{n-1}-\frac{1}{2}}$. They are iid with mean $1$.

Then $M_n = e^{W_n - \frac{n}{2}}$ and it's well known that $M_n \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} 0$.

Once again, this implies the impossibility of the $L^1$ convergence because $\mathbb{E}[M_n] = 1$.